# Automatic generation of the move constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    A() {}
    A(const A &a) {
        cout << "copy constructor" << endl;
    }
    A& operator=(const A &a) {
        cout << "assigment operator" << endl;
    }
    A(A &&a) {
        cout << "move" << endl;
    }
    A& operator=(A &&a) {
        cout << "move" << endl;
    }
};

struct B {
    A a;
};

B func() {
    B b;
    return b;
}
int main() {
    B b = func();
}
```

This prints "copy constructor".

For class B the move constructor and the move assignment operator should be automatic generated correct? But why is it using the copy constructor of class A and not the move constructor?

Comment: I think you need to create explicit-implicit constructor for the B class (`B::B(A&& _a) : a(_a) { }`), but I'm not sure, so posting it as comment. I think that also `std::forward` may be needed, but still, I'll leave it to C++ gurus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it doesn't print anything at all because the copy/move has been elided.  However if I thwart RVO with something like:

```
extern bool choice;

B func() {
    B b1, b2;
    if (choice)
      return b1;
    return b2;
}
```

Then it prints:

```
move
```

It may be that your compiler does not yet implement the automatic generation of the move members.

Comment: +1.  You beat me to it; this looks like a deficiency (bug) in the questioner's C++11 compiler.

Comment: im using visual studio 2010, maybe its not implemented yet

Comment: Quite likely.  That compiler shipped before the committee settled the question of whether or not to even have implicitly generated move members.